# Feeds Import - Entity Reference mapping

Tags: entities, feeds

I have a "Buildings" content type. Within that content type I have a building_id field, which contains the building ID.

I have an "Employee" content type. Within that content type I have an entity reference to the Buildings content type.

I have a CSV file for employees but it does not have the building label or the node id, only the building_id.

So my issue is that when I run the employee feed import, I cannot add the building since I only have the building_id.

How would I map the building_id in my csv to match the building_id in the building content type so that it knows which building node it is referencing?

I hope that makes sense :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past I used Views Data Export to build a spreadsheet in Views that contain the NID and the plain text field I needed to use as a reference.

Then in Excel, you can use VLOOKUP to join 2 excel files based on a common column (building_id) so  that way you can obtain the entity referenced nid you need for your import.

Comment: You sir, are a lifesaver. That worked great! Thanks again.